# Checking database for existing data via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, validation

I have a working registration script with PHP validation.

I am now converting it to run via AJAX.

I can understand validating forms in terms of the val of the inputs. e.g. empty, format and content etc.

But I need help with checking if a username already exists in the database.

So, I have this for the PHP side:

```
        $query = " SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE username = :username "; 

    $query_params = array( 
        ':username' => $_POST['username'] 
    ); 

    try 
    { 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    { 
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    } 
    $row = $stmt->fetch(); 

    if($row) 
    { 
    echo 'Username Taken';
    die(); 
    }
```

I have used AJAX else where on my site but only for simple validation and the code is e.g:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".registerform").submit(function(){
    var $targetForm = $(this);

    $targetForm.find(".error").remove();
    $targetForm.find(".success").remove();

    // If there is anything wrong with 
    // validation we set the check to false
    var check = true;

    // Get the values
    var username = $('.regusername').val();
    var password = $('.regemail').val();
    var email = $('.regpassword').val();
    var ut = response.usernameTaken;

    // Username Validation

    // If isername empty
    if (username == '') {
        check = false;
        $('.regusername').css('border', 'solid 2px red');
    } else {
        $('.regusername').css('border', 'solid 2px green');
    }



  // ... goes after Validation
    if (check == true) {
        ShowAjaxLoader();
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "process/register.php",
data: $targetForm.serialize(),
dataType: "json",
success: function(response){

    if (response.databaseSuccess == true)
; // ok
    else
; //error

}
        });
    }
    return false;
});
});
```

Any help on what the next step is for validating items in the database.

I was going to do a JSON return e.g.

```
$return['emailTaken'] = true;
echo json_encode($return);
```

and then check for that in the AJAX validation but just... dont think its the right way to do it.

Sorry if its really basic knowledge. Just need pointing in right direction.

Comment: To check if a user exists, try `if ( $stmt->rowCount() > 0 ) { echo "Exists"; }`

Comment: You should really consider using a framework, no matter how "small" your app may be. That said, here's a tut that does what you are creating w/o framework, that may be helpful to read through http://codebyjeff.com/blog/2013/04/how-do-i-use-ajax-with-framework-x

Answer (score 0):

I would return an error message, and the class/id of the field that caused the error. That way, you can display an error message, and mark the field so it's easier for users to see where they need to correct something.

```
{
  'errorMsg':'e-mail address already taken',
  'formField': 'regemail'
}
```

Or something similar.
This could also be wrapped into an array, so you could return multiple errors (often useful in large forms)